# console input not working for netbeans ide 7.4 with scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, junit4, netbeans-7

I have a netbeans project with test classes junit-4.1 and want to read in some numbers from console using the scanner class. System.out.println... works fine but, when I input something in the netbeans console, then code execution stops where the scanner reads in. Waiting forever...

here is the code

```
private int controllerByteToWhiteCell() { 

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please choose one of the following options 1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,15");

    String cmd = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("cmd = " + cmd);

return Integer.parseInt(cmd);
}
```

running Test/File on the test file which calls the upper code lines, I get output in the netbeans IDE 7.4 console

```
T E S T S
------------------------------------------
Running deltaanalytics.ftir.hardware.jueke.controller.JuekeCommandServiceTest
getBytesArrayToWhiteCell

Please choose one of the following options 1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12,13,14,15

11
```

after entering a number 11 + carriage return, execution of code stops, no otuput from next System.out.println appears

if I run this code outside netbeans IDE it works! (without use of junit tests). Do I have to redirect System.in somehow? How can I check that the IDE console waits  for System.in input?

Comment: Would updating Netbeans a possible solution? It is working with Netbeans 8. Have tested it with 8.0.2 and 8.1.